# Apache: Adding AddOutputFilterByType or other directives inside a VirtualHost overrides previous directives

Tags: php, docker, apache, debian

**Edit**: the issue has been reported to the official Docker image: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1326

I am using the latest official Docker PHP Apache image ([php:8.1.8-apache-bullseye](https://hub.docker.com/_/php)), which bundles Debian Apache 2.4.48.

I have set up a very simple VirtualHost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/app/docroot
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    <Directory "/srv/app/docroot">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This file is enabled via the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.8-apache-bullseye

COPY . /srv/app

COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /srv/app
```

It works fine, but I noticed that default Debian Apache configuration is not ideal for modern websites. For example, it does not compress SVG files, and it does not include the `image/avif` MIME type for AVIF images.

When I try to add this, it seems to work fine with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        <IfModule mod_filter.c>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddType image/avif avif
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, after adding these lines to `vhost.conf`, I am losing the standard configuration Debian includes. E.g. CSS/JavaScript files are no longer compressed with gzip, and webp MIME type is not set for webp images.

Is there a reason why adding directives in my VirtualHost file may override previously set directives?

Duplicating the already set directives works fine:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/wasm
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And for some reason, setting the `AddType` directive outside the `<IfModule mod_mime.c>` conditional also works fine (it adds the new type without replacing other types):

```
AddType image/avif avif
```

**Update**: this is no longer happening to me in latest Docker images, I'm pretty sure I experienced it before though.

Comment: This question should be asked on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Good point. I guess there is no way to move it, especially if I want to keep the bounty?

Comment: @Olivier For reference, asking for help here is suggested at the top of https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Comment: both mod_mime and mod_filter merge their configuration by combining the base (global config) and overrides (vhost config) so it should not happen. Similarly, the ifmodule should have no such impact.

Comment: I confirm this issue in a completely unrelated configuration, have you found any solution besides duplicating the default mime types?

Comment: @mmomtchev not really. As you can see in the GitHub issue, the Docker maintainer believes it's not a specific issue with the Docker image, but I'm not sure if this is an issue on the Debian side or in Apache

Comment: I have in on Debian too, but not inside a Docker container - so he is right.

Comment: @mmomtchev Interesting, is your issue in mod_filter.c, mod_mime.c, or both? It would be great to reproduce the issue on other distributions, to be able to understand if this is Debian-specific or an Apache bug.

Comment: I've just bumped into this one in a Debian container using Apache 2.4.56, although in my case I'm actually trying to prevent compression from being added to 1 particular script (long story), while keeping it for the majority of scripts with the same MIME type.

If you put AddOutputFilterByType in an If/Else, it'll also override an AddOutputFilterByType outside that block within the same virtualhost. 

I suspect this is intentional, since there's no other way to remove a filter added via AddOutputFilterByType. 

It would be nice if the documentation clarified this though...

Comment: I've reported bugs for Apache modules before (and had them fix it same day), so I'll raise an issue to clarify the documentation at least...

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is intended behaviour, although I might be wrong.

I've raised an issue on the ASF Bugzilla to clarify the documentation: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66648

However, I've noticed that the documentation for "AddOutputFilter" states the following: "Note that when defining a set of filters using the AddOutputFilter directive, any definition made will replace any previous definition made by the AddOutputFilter directive."

I know AddOutputFilterByType is different from AddOutputFilter, but I suspect that it has the same intended behaviour in terms of sections/contexts. Hopefully a contributor to httpd or mod_filter will be able to weigh in on that Bugzilla ticket.

Comment: Thanks! Would you say it's also the same case with AddType?

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate for AddType: "This mapping is added to any already in force, overriding any mappings that already exist for the same extension."

Comment: Thanks! I tested it, and I am no longer experiencing that AddType issue. (And unrelated, but I see that Debian Bookworm may have added `AddType image/avif avif`, which makes now that specific configuration unnecessary for me, anyway)